# C#: Creating a computer object in AD fails

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have created a toolbox to create computers in various management systems (including Active Directory). This toolbox has worked flawlessly for years. Since this month the creation of the computer object in Active Directory does not work anymore. I am still looking for the cause, but seems to be related to a patch on the Domain Controllers.
Nothing has been changed on the user that creates the object.
When I manually create a client with the user credentials using the following command, it works fine.

```
New-ADComputer -Name NB89991 -Path "ou=nb,ou=w10,ou=clt,ou=tier2,ou=central,dc=xy-dom,dc=xy,dc=ch" -SAMAccountName NB89991
```

Do you know what could be wrong with my code?

```
 public Boolean createComputerAccount(Client computer){
        Boolean returnValue = true;
        try {
            if (!existComputer(computer))
            {

                PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = GetPrincipalContext(computer.ou);
                ComputerPrincipal computerPrincipal = new ComputerPrincipal(oPrincipalContext);
                computerPrincipal.SamAccountName = computer.name;
                computerPrincipal.Name = computer.name;
                if (!(computer.adDescription == "")) {
                    computerPrincipal.Description = computer.adDescription;
                }

                
                MessageBox.Show(computerPrincipal.SamAccountName, "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                MessageBox.Show(computerPrincipal.Name, "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

                computerPrincipal.Enabled = true;
                computerPrincipal.Save();
                returnValue = true;
            }
            else {
                returnValue = false;
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            errorMessage = "Creating a computer in Active Directory failed!\r\nPlease contact the ITCM TEAM or check the Logfile:\r\n (c:\\temp\\ClientToolbox.log).";
            createErrorMessage(errorMessage, e);
            returnValue = false;
        }
     return returnValue;
    }

    public PrincipalContext GetPrincipalContext(string sOU) {
        PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain, sOU, ContextOptions.SimpleBind, ntUser, ntUserPWD);
        return oPrincipalContext;
    }
```

Error Message:

27.12.2021 16:19:46
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied.

at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.Insert(Principal p)
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.Save()
at ClientToolbox.ActiveDirectory.createComputerAccount(Client computer) in C:\Temp\Win10Toolbox\Source\AZToolboxClient\MyClasses\ActiveDirectory.cs:line 71

Thanks a lot!
Best regards
ynick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[KB5008102](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5008102-active-directory-security-accounts-manager-hardening-changes-cve-2021-42278-5975b463-4c95-45e1-831a-d120004e258e) says this:

> The sAMAccountName of a computer account whose UserAccountControl attribute contains the UF_WORKSTATION_TRUST_ACCOUNT flag must end with a single dollar sign ($).

So you need to add that `$` to the `SamAccountName`:

```
computerPrincipal.SamAccountName = computer.name + "$";
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriel. That was the solution. Do you know why a "$" at the end is not needed for the following command?

New-ADComputer -Name NB89991 -Path "ou=nb,ou=w10,ou=clt,ou=tier2,ou=central,dc=xy-dom,dc=xy,dc=ch" -SAMAccountName NB89991

Comment: `New-ADComputer` adds the `$` for you.

Answer (score 0):

Update: 27.12.2021:
I think the issue occurs because of the following Microsoft article.
I have not get yet how i have to change my code that it works again. Does everyone know?

[Microsoft KB5008102](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5008102-active-directory-security-accounts-manager-hardening-changes-cve-2021-42278-5975b463-4c95-45e1-831a-d120004e258e)

Comment: This isn't an answer.  If you want to clarify your question, edit it using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70497534/edit).

Comment: Harvey is right, something entered as "answer" should answer the question. You can easily edit your question with the additional information and delete this (non-) answer.